# Listview is not populating all columns in a vertical manner

Tags: c#, listview

**Background:**

I have lists which store parsed data from sqlite columns. I want to show these lists in a listview to the user. They click a button and the list view should show these 3 lists and their contents.

The three lists are called, SeqIrregularities, MaxLen, and PercentPopList.

**Problem:** *The listview is being populated in a horizontal manner (Shown below) which only contains contents of* **Seqirregularities** list.The other 2 don't even show up. ***I*** ***want the listview to have contents of each list, vertically in the corresponding list column.***

Side note: The listview is skipping the first column, another problem, but I can fix that.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
 ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(); 
            foreach (object o in SeqIrregularities )
            {
                lvi.SubItems.Add(o.ToString());
            }
            foreach (object a in MaxLen )
            {
                lvi.SubItems.Add(a.ToString()); 
            }
            foreach (object b in PercentPopList)
            {
                lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ToString()); 
            }

            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Comment: It's skipping the first item because you're not sending any `text` into the constructor.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but what about the real problem? The problem is that the listview is being horizontally populated instead of vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are adding items to `ListViewItem` object and assigning it to `ListView` it will create a single row because `ListViewItem` represents one row in `ListView`. from your code you are adding `ListViewItem` only one time, hence you will get only one Row that is Horizontally.

if you need to get the Multiple Rows (Vertically) you need to add the multiple `ListViewItem` objects to `ListView` .

```
        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(); 
        foreach (object o in SeqIrregularities )
        {
            lvi.SubItems.Add(o.ToString());
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
        lvi = new ListViewItem();

        foreach (object a in MaxLen )
        {
            lvi.SubItems.Add(a.ToString()); 
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
        lvi = new ListViewItem();

        foreach (object b in PercentPopList)
        {
            lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ToString()); 
        }

        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);//Adds a new row
```

Comment: Hey, your reply is very helpful but there are just a few mistakes with it. You're populating EACH ROW with the different list. I want to populate each COLUMN, with a different list. Can you pls give me your email adress? I need to show you a picture (jpg) of what I mean. Thanks Sir !

Comment: sorry I forgot to tag you @Sudhakar

Comment: sudhakar.tillapudi@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks, I will email you soon